# Parallel read of a nxn matrix stored in a file

Tags: file, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm developing a program, to solve the equation Ax = B using Gaussian Elimination. I've got a file, in which I've stored a matrix of type double (row major order since using C). I'm trying to read the file in parallel, by using the parallel file I/O functions provided by MPI.

I've gained some understanding of `MPI_File_set_view` and how it logically partitions the shared file so that each process has a different view of the file. I've also understood that a view must consist of an `etype`, a `filetype` and a displacement. Now in my case, I've got to have a cyclic row distribution and for this I've got the following code:

```
int count, blksize, stride,lb,extent;
    MPI_File fh;
    MPI_Offset of;
    /* Define types for etype, ftype
      etype: Type of data stored in the file. 
      ftype: Description of HOW the data is stored in the file.
       */
    MPI_Datatype etype, ftype,mpi_vect;
    /* etype:

     */
    count = (n + (size -1))/size; blksize = n;
    stride = size;
    lb = 0; extent = n*sizeof(double);
    MPI_Type_vector(count,blksize,stride,MPI_DOUBLE,&mpi_vect);
    MPI_Type_create_resized(mpi_vect,lb,extent,&etype);
    MPI_Type_commit(&etype);    

    /* ftype: Describes the logical division of file.
      A strided vector of blocksize 1 and count n/size.
      Stride is size
    */
     MPI_Type_vector(count,1,stride, MPI_DOUBLE, &ftype);
     MPI_Type_commit(&ftype);
    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD,filename,MPI_MODE_RDONLY,MPI_INFO_NULL,&fh);
    MPI_File_set_view(fh,0,etype,ftype,native,MPI_INFO_NULL);
    /* Assume buf is allocated as an mpi_vector with blocksize equal to row size and stride equal to number of processors */
    MPI_File_read(fh,buf,count,mpi_vec,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

My question is, how do I decide the proper etype and ftype? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`etype` and `ftype` still trip me up and I've been working with MPI-IO for 15 years.  The concept isn't so tough, but for some reason the naming convention does not stick with me.

the `etype` or "elementary type" sets the fundamental unit for various counts.   When you call `MPI_File_read_at_all` and give an offset, that offset is a count of `etype`.  Not bytes.

There are two ways to read a particular region of a file: you can adjust the file view on each process to start where you want, or  you can use the explicit offset routines (e.g. `MPI_File_read_at_all`).   If you are constructing a file view for each process you might not even need to worry about the etype: set it to MPI_BYTE.

Comment: I can agree. I've decided to switch back to traditional I/O.

Comment: that wasn't the point I was trying to make!  you're pretty close. do you want each processor to read a row of the matrix?

Comment: It's a different scenario, I want the processes to read the matrix in a block cyclic fashion. Conveniently, it is in row major order that I want them to access

Comment: sounds like you want MPI_TYPE_CREATE_DARRAY

Comment: Yeah but I can't figure out how to use row wise decomposition with that